# Spring boot Issue IllegalArgumentException when using Order By in Repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, crud

im having an annoying issue where I cant seem to find a solution for.

Im currently implementing a way to read only the top 500 Entries ordered by Date. If I dont enter the Order By, Spring boot delivers the top 500 which is fine, but as soon as I include the Order By Option I get this Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.sma.db.repositories.LogRepository.findTop500ByOrderBylogsLogTimeDesc()! No property orderBylogsLogTimeDesc found for type LogEntity!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
```

As it seems, Spring boot includes the Order by and and looks for a property named orderbylogsLogTimeDesc . What I also dont understand is, why order is written in lower cases.

Does anyone know a solution for this? It is really annoying and I cant seem to find a solution :(

Repository:
@Repository

```
public interface LogRepository extends JpaRepository<LogEntity, Long>{
   // List<FeedEntity> deleteByfeedTimestamp(Date feed_timestamp);
   List<LogEntity>findTop500ByOrderBylogsLogTimeDesc();
}
```

Entity:

```
@Column(name = "logs_logtime")
private Date logsLogTime;

   public Date getLogsLogTime() {
    return logsLogTime;
}

public void setLogsLogTime(Date logsLogTime) {
    this.logsLogTime = logsLogTime;
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class LogService {
 
    @Autowired
    private LogRepository repo;
     
    public List<LogEntity> getLogs() {
        return repo.findTop500ByOrderBylogsLogTimeDesc();
    }
```

Ive found the solution in the end: I had to write **L**ogsLogTime instead of logsLogTime... . It works now :) Thanks!

Comment: A small tip: Have a look at Pageable. Then you can get a paged and sorted result back. BR

Comment: thanks for the Tip. I'll take a look into that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guys gave me an idea. I actually found the Issue! When i typed LogsLogTime it worked as in:

findTop500ByOrderBy**L**ogsLogTimeDesc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to specify the field twice, have you tried:

```java
List<LogEntity>findTop500ByLogsLogTimeOrderByLogsLogTimeDesc();
```